# Android Testing - API levels to test

Tags: android, testing

I have 2 AVDs – one for API level 19 and API level 8. If I test my app on both version, does that mean it will work with everything in between?

Comment: generally there's no need to support the API level 8  most apps start from  API 10 , but , yes if it works on both , it will work on between.

Comment: great. Thanks. I had to use API level 8 to test the rotation (landscape)  in the emulator. Bug in SDK/Eclipse, does not let the application to rotate with CTRL + F12 even though the emulator rotates. Sucks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. API levels are backward compatible which means if you write a code for

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="20" />
```

That means your code will run on all devices in between.

Answer (score 0):

The probability is high that it will work for frameworks in between if is is working on 19 and 8 both. But there are constant changes in some methods that may change the behavior in some cases.